# Get text of php file without executing it - using GAS urlfetch()

Tags: google-apps-script, mime-types, urlfetch

I'm using a general Google Apps Script function to be able to read, prettify and publish Google Apps Script code and data from a scriptdb. I've recently extended it to publish code from a Gist or from a given web address. The purpose it to be able to include live code snippets in documentation. I have it all working fine [for most use cases](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gaspublish), including for html and other server based files.

However, php files get executed rather (than returned as text/html) when accessed with urlFetch(). I know it's along shot, but does anyone know of any header options, or indeed any other technique, I can use to generally override this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for would be a major security problem. It is not possible to ask for the php-code instead of the result of the php script execution. Well, not exactly - it is up to the Server hosting that php script what it does with it. If there was no php extension installed on the server it would return the php code or the file as whole.

But to help with your request:
You should ask the server administrator / website owner if the code is available somewhere and if so what the url is. I believe there is a php extension that allows files to be looked at with colors, text indent and everything - but i think it is disabled by default (or you need to rename your php file to something else)

Comment: Yes I figured that it would be a long shot. I am the web site owner and i do already make a copy of the php file for publishing as you have suggested here. i was looking for a way to get the latest public code  without making a copy under a different mime type. Thank you for your reply.